# How can I read a file multiple times in java

Tags: java, file-io

This is my understanding regarding reading a file using `BufferedReader` in java. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere...

Recently I had a requirement where we are required to read a file multiple times.

The usual way which I use is setting a `mark()` and doing a reset. But the input parameters to
a mark is an integer and it cannot accept a long number. Is there a way in which we can read the file, a large number of times.

In c++ we can do a seekg on the `fstream` and `read` the contents once again irrespective of the number of times we want to do so. Is there anything in java which is of this nature.

Comment: Mayb [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) can help

Comment: Do you really want to allocate a buffer with a size larger than 2 billion? From the javadoc: "*An attempt to reset the stream after reading characters up to this limit or beyond may fail. A limit value larger than the size of the input buffer will cause **a new buffer to be allocated whose size is no smaller than limit. Therefore large values should be used with care**.*"

Comment: Look at java.io.RandomAccessFile

Comment: This might help. Read file once and use the data multiple times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813617/read-the-file-once-and-use-the-data-multiple-times

Comment: Have you considered using a `java.nio.Channel` ? @MadProgrammer CHANNELS !! :D

Comment: @LittleChild I've had more success with RandomAccessFile

Answer (score 3):

Just close the file and read it again.

But review your requirement. Why can't you process it in one pass?

Comment: Yes - reading the file multiple times is a _solution_ not a _requirement_ Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not much of a good answer but if you want to do random reading and writing then you can use `Channels` in `java.nio` package.

`BufferedReader` is for reading a file when you logically see it as a series of records and records are generally accessed sequentially.
`Channel`s allow you to view your file as a series of blocks. Blocks are meant to be read randomly. :)

Using subclass of channel, `FileChannel`, you can read what you want from wherever you want. You need to specify two things:

1. Where to read from.
2. How much to read.

It has a `read(dst,pstn)` where `dst` is a `ByteBuffer` and pstn is a `long` position.

Don't worry that it is `abstract` because you use it via `Files.newByteChannel()` which does all the voodoo needed to make it work :)